# What is the correct answer for this confusing AWS question

Tags: amazon-web-services, certificate

A user has created photo editing software and hosted it on EC2. The software accepts requests from the user about the photo format and resolution and sends a message to S3 to enhance the picture accordingly. Which of the below mentioned AWS services will help make a scalable software with the AWS infrastructure in this scenario?

A. AWS Simple Queue Service
B. AWS Simple Notification Service
C. AWS Glacier
D. AWS Elastic Transcoder

I think it should be D AWS Elastic Transcoder. What do u think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the AWS Elastic Transcoder with AWS Lambda + SQS. So whenever the server has any request from a user it will transfer the payload to SQS and SQS will trigger the Lambda. Now Lambda will do all business logic with AWS Elastic Transcoder. In this way, it can handle lots of traffic using SQL and Lambda. You can manage the Lambda thread and SQS queue pool.

Comment: So the combination of both A and D could the correct answer from this multiple choice question?

Comment: Yes You can use it.

Comment: @MasiBoo we can't use AWS Elastic Transcoder in this scenario because it is solely used for video purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS. is a fast, reliable, scalable, and fully managed message queuing service. SQS provides a simple and cost-effective way to decouple the components of an application. The user can configure SQS, which will decouple the call between the EC2 application and S3. Thus, the application does not keep waiting for S3 to provide the data.

> Glacier is for cold storage, Transcoder is sorely for video, SNS is
> for notification, hence only SQS could help in processing fragments by
> fragments information for the application. So the answer is A (AWS SQS)